# Add an empty series on an Excel chart

Tags: vba, excel, charts, series

I'm trying to add many series to a chart using VBA, as in the code below.

```
For i = 0 To 9
    Set serNew = chtMap.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    With serNew
        .XValues = Range("Y4").Cells(1, 1 + 2 * i).Resize(32000, 1) 
        .Values = Range("Y4").Cells(1, 2 + 2 * i).Resize(32000, 1) 
    End With
Next i
```

The ranges for some of the series have no data in their cells yet; the user will write/load this data later. The idea is to have the chart ready for when they do.

**Problem**: when the loop hits such a yet empty range, I get an error 1004: Unable to set XValues property of the Series class. Why and is there a way around this?

The weird thing is that doing this manually in Chart menu --> |Source Data... works perfectly fine. Actually, if you record a macro while doing this manually, the result is as follows:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(4).XValues = "=Sheet2!R4C31:R32003C31"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(4).Values = "=Sheet2!R4C32:R32003C32"
```

but then Excel gives an error when re-playing this macro!

Doing this manually is not a pleasant prospect. I guess I could stick sham data in the cells, create the series, and then delete the sham data. Do I really have to pull such a bait and switch on Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to add a sheet button that calls a sub that can add the series *after* the data has been entered. It also checks whether the various ranges are empty before actually adding each series. This feels like the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to copy the range (both columns), and use paste special to add it to the chart:

```
TwoColumnRange.Copy
chtMap.SeriesCollection.Paste Rowcol:=xlColumns, SeriesLabels:=False, _
    CategoryLabels:=True, Replace:=False, NewSeries:=True
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest (as I have done myself) to hide some fake data somewhere and have all the series default to point there. Also hide the series from the plot with `.LineStyle=xlNone` and `.MarkeStyle=xlNone` and even `ActiveChart.Legend.LegendEntries(i).Delete`. Then when customer fills in the data, run a macro that replaces where the series points, and sets the line/marker styles, as well as `ActiveChart.HasLegend = True` to recreate the legend entries. If fact I had to switch the legend off and then on again for things to reset properly.

Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, that's partly what I suggested myself in the question... Sort of a depressing solution, isn't it.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but...

I just wrote this code and tested in Excel 2010 and 2016. It adds a new series to an existing XY Scatter chart, and the new series formula links to the blank ranges used for .Name, .Values, and .XValues:

```
Sub AddBlankSeries()
  Dim srs As Series

  Set srs = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries

  With srs
    .Name = "=" & ActiveSheet.Range("E2").Address(, , , True)
    .Values = ActiveSheet.Range("E3:E8")
    .XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("D3:D8")
  End With
End Sub
```

Then I went back to the original code:

```
Sub AddSeveralBlankSeries()
  Dim i As Long
  Dim chtMap As Chart
  Dim serNew As Series

  Set chtMap = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlXYScatterLines).Chart

  For i = 0 To 9
    Set serNew = chtMap.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    With serNew
      .XValues = Range("Y4").Cells(1, 1 + 2 * i).Resize(32000, 1)
      .Values = Range("Y4").Cells(1, 2 + 2 * i).Resize(32000, 1)
    End With
  Next i
End Sub
```

This also ran fine, and the series references the expected ranges in the worksheet.

So I don't know what the problem was.